# ¿Cómo inserto los valores “start_date” y “end_date” manualmente si solo se entrega el auth_user_id en un post?

Tags: django

**model**

```
from django.db import models

class OfficeAccess(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField('id')
start_date = models.DateTimeField('start_date')
end_date = models.DateTimeField('end_date')
auth_user_id = models.IntegerField('auth_user_id', max_length=11)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

# default=datetime.now, blank=True

class Meta:
    db_table = 'office_access'
    verbose_name = 'office_access'
    verbose_name_plural = 'office_access'
    ordering = ('-id',)

def natural_key(self):
    return self.id

@staticmethod
def get_object(id):
    try:
        return OfficeAccess.objects.get(id=id)
    except OfficeAccess.DoesNotExist:
        return False
```

**Serializer**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rems.models.OfficeAccess import OfficeAccess


class OfficeAccessSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
auth_user_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
start_date = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
end_date = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)

class Meta:
    model = OfficeAccess
    fields = ('id', 'auth_user_id', 'start_date', 'end_date')
```

**View**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rems.serializers.OfficeAcessSerializer import OfficeAccessSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rems.models.OfficeAccess import OfficeAccess
from rems.common.helpers.ErrorsHelper import ErrorsHelper
from rems.models.Auth_User import Auth_User
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta


class OfficeAccessSaveService(APIView):
def post(self, request, format=None):
    conditions = OfficeAccessSaveService.get_conditions(request.data)
    # si se ingresa auth_user_id, si es correcto, si existe y end_date is null
    if conditions['auth_user_id_provided'] and conditions['auth_user_id_correct'] \
            and conditions['auth_user_id_exist']:
        return OfficeAccessSaveService.update_or_create(request.data, conditions)
    else:
        return ErrorsHelper.return_not_found_error('auth_user_id')

@staticmethod
def update_or_create(data, conditions):
    if OfficeAccessSaveService.want_to_create(data=data):
        return OfficeAccessSaveService.try_to_create(data, conditions)
    return OfficeAccessSaveService.try_to_update(data, conditions)

@staticmethod
def get_conditions(data, auth_user_id_provided=None, auth_user_id=None):

    # Inicializar la variable a devolver
    auth_user_instance = False
    office_access_instance = False

    conditions = {
        "auth_user_id_provided": False,
        "auth_user_id_correct": False,
        "auth_user_id_exist": False,
        "auth_user": False,
        "office_access": False,
        # "end_date_is_null": False
    }
    if 'auth_user_id' in data:
        conditions['auth_user_id_provided'] = True
        if data['auth_user_id'] > 0:
            conditions['auth_user_id_correct'] = True
            auth_user_instance = Auth_User.get_object(data['auth_user_id'])
            if auth_user_instance:
                conditions['auth_user_id_exist'] = True
                conditions['auth_user'] = auth_user_instance
                office_access_instance = OfficeAccess.objects.filter(end_date=None
                                                                     , auth_user_id=auth_user_id)
                if office_access_instance:
                    conditions['office_access'] = True
                    conditions['office_access'] = office_access_instance

    return conditions

@staticmethod
def want_to_create(data):
    if 'id' not in data:
        return True

@staticmethod
def try_to_create(data, conditions):
    serializer = OfficeAccessSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return ErrorsHelper.return_serializer_errors(serializer.errors)

@staticmethod
def try_to_update(data, conditions):
    id = data.get('id')
    if not id > 0:
        return Response(['Wrong parameter: id'], status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    office_access_object = OfficeAccess.get_object(id)
    serializer = OfficeAccessSerializer(office_access_object, data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return ErrorsHelper.return_serializer_errors(serializer.errors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente sobrescribe el método save de tu serializer, y agrega los valores que desees poner, esto es un ejemplo de ello:

```
class OfficeAccessSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    auth_user_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    start_date = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
    end_date = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = OfficeAccess
        fields = ('id', 'auth_user_id', 'start_date', 'end_date')

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        """Adds some aditional data to the OfficeAcessModel and returns it.:

        start_date
        end_date
        """

        OfficeAccessInstance = super(OfficeAccessSerializer, self).save(**kwargs)

        OfficeAccessInstance.start_date = datetime.datetime('La fecha que desees  poner')
        OfficeAccessInstance.end_date = datetime.datetime('La fecha que desees poner')

        OfficeAccessInstance.save()

        return OfficeAccessInstance
```

Puedes hacer la lógica que desees para crear esos datos. Pero en esencia es esto, ademas recuerda hacer la validación de que los datos no existan de tal manera que no tengas incoherencia, un saludo ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias Cheke